# How can identify the one statement inside if without braces?

Tags: c, if-statement, nested

normally without braces we define one statement so

I want to ask

```
 if ( n > 0 )
       if ( m > 0 ) 
         printf("Condition satisfied.");
```

is this one statement or

```
if ( n > 0 )
       if ( m > 0 ) 
         printf(" Condition satisfied.");
  else 
     printf(" condition not satisfied. ");
```

so I ask from above two codes which is right code? and give out put for this code

```
if(a > b)
if(b > c)
s1;
else s2;
s2 will be executed if
```

Comment: You can figure this out by trying all four cases `n=0 m=0`, `n=0 m=1`, `n=1 m=0`, `n=1 m=1`, and see what the output is.

Comment: output is not a case . I want to ask , we can define only one statement when we declare "if" without braces. so here we define two statements in outter  if condition

Comment: You can search for “dangling else” — your second example illustrates it beautifully.  And GCC with enough warnings enabled will let you know about the problem.

Comment: One of many reasons why `if`/`else` without `{ }` is dangerous style and should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a case like this:

```
if ( n > 0 )
       if ( m > 0 ) 
         printf(" Condition satisfied.");
  else 
     printf(" condition not satisfied. ");
```

The `else` pairs with the innermost `if`.  So the above is the same as:

```
if ( n > 0 ) {
    if ( m > 0 ) {
        printf(" Condition satisfied.");
    } else  {
        printf(" condition not satisfied. ");   
    }
}
```

Such cases can be potentially confusing, so unless you can put the entire statement cleanly on one line, always use braces to be clear what goes where.

Answer (score 0):

This C Tutorial explains “Dangling else” in C. It explains the association of single else statement in a nested if statement.
In nested if statements, when a single “else clause” occurs, the situation happens to be dangling else! For example:

```
  if (condition)
        if (condition)
        if (condition)
    else
        printf("dangling else!\n");  /* dangling else, as to which if statement, else clause associates */
```

**1. In such situations, else clause belongs to the closest if statement which is incomplete that is the innermost if statement!**
2. However, we can make else clause belong to desired if statement by enclosing all if statements in block outer to which if statement to associate the else clause. For example:

```
      if (condition) {
        if (condition)
            if (condition)
    } else
        printf("else associates with the outermost if statement!\n");
```

Comment: What does *This C tutorial* mean? For a good answer you should apply proper formatting to your code. This kind of "random" indentation is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you write something like

```
if(n > 0)
    if(m > 0) 
        printf("Condition satisfied.\n");
else 
    printf("Condition not satisfied.\n");
```

then, yes, you've got the "dangling else" problem.  It can be hard to figure out which `if` the `else` goes with.  By using explicit braces, you can definitively associate the `else` with the correct `if`.

*But*, in this case, it's not correct to associate the `else` with either of the `if`s!  In this case, I believe you'd want to write it like this:

```
if(n > 0 && m > 0) 
      printf("Condition satisfied.\n");
else  printf("Condition not satisfied.\n");
```

Now, not only is it smaller and easier to read, not only is there no dangling else problem, but you'll always get a correct result, with one or the other message printed.